# Входная строка имела неверный формат

Tags: pascal

Здравствуйте.

Программа читает файл и печатает содержимое на экран.

```
program aaa;

var 
    f: text;
    s: string;
    i: integer;

begin
    assign(f, '1.txt');
    reset(f);
    while not eof(f) do begin
        readln(f, s, i);
        writeln(s, ' ', i);
    end;
end.
```

Но при попытке запустить PascalABC.NET говорит:

```
Ошибка времени исполнения: Входная строка имела неверный формат.
```

В чем может быть ошибка?
Содержимое входного файла:

```
mynamw 334
myeemw 334
mynrrramw 334
```

Comment: Кстати, вы читаете много раз, а выводите на консоль только один раз, последнюю строку файла (если он непуст). Это не баг?

Comment: Да, получается, съел строку. Вывод: "mynrrramw 334 100".

Comment: Исправил, должен считывать из файла и печатать.

Comment: [Справка по процедуре ReadLn](http://delphibasics.ru/ReadLn.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Рискну предположить, что `readln` гордо считал "mynamw 334" в `s`, и дальше не смог найти ничего похожего на `i`. Откуда ему знать, где заканчивается ваша строка и есть ли в ней пробелы? Попробуйте заменить это на просто `readln(f, s); i := 100;` и посмотреть, что будет.

---

Итак, проблему нашли. А можно переставить местами данные:

> 334 mynamw
> 334 myeemw
> 334 mynrrramw

?

Если да, то всё получится с `readln(f, i, s);`.

---

Поскольку мы решили не менять формат, задача становится сложнее :) Я бы считал всю строку в строковую переменную (`readln(f, line);`), а дальше нашёл бы в ней последний пробел (поиском с конца) и разделил по нему на `s` (подстрока от начала до позиции найденного пробела) и `i` (остаток строки, перевести в число с помощью `StrToInt`). Понятно, как?

Comment: Так-то все получается, но хотелось бы, чтобы в начале была текстовая строка (переменной длины).

Comment: @maxsynergy: обновил ответ

Comment: Понял, придется все-таки разбивать на подстроки.

Comment: @maxsynergy: угу, раз `readln` с этим справиться не может.

Comment: Ясно, спасибо!